# Regex not matching words delimited by whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string that will follow the pattern `/user/<id>?name=<name>`, where `<id>` is alphanumeric but must start with a letter, and `<name>` is a letter-only string that can have multiple spaces. Some examples of matches would be:

```
/user/ad?name=a a
/user/one111?name=one ONE oNe
/user/hello?name=world
```

I came up with the following regex:

```
String regex = "/user/[a-zA-Z]+\\w*\\?name=[a-zA-Z\\s]+";
```

All of the above examples match the regex, but it only looks at the first word in `<name>`. Shouldn't the sequence `\s` allow me to have white spaces?

The code that I made to test what it is doing is:

```
String regex = "/user/[a-zA-Z]+\\w*\\?name=[a-zA-Z\\s]+";
// Check to see that input matches pattern
if(Pattern.matches(regex, str) == true){
   str = str.replaceFirst("/user/", "");
   str = str.replaceFirst("name=", "");
   String[] tokens = str.split("\\?");
   System.out.println("size = " + tokens.length);
   System.out.println("tokens[0] = " + tokens[0]);
   System.out.println("tokens[1] = " + tokens[1]);
} else
    System.out.println("Didn't match.");
```

So for example, one test might look like:

```
/user/myID123?name=firstName LastName
size = 2
tokens[0] = myID123
tokens[1] = firstName
```

whereas the desired output would be

```
tokens[1] = firstName LastName
```

How can I change my regex to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you think is the problem in your code. `tokens[1]` **will** indeed contain `firstName LastName` in your example.

Here's an [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/sDKfL) showing this.

---

However, have you considered using capturing groups for the id and the name.

If you write it like

```
String regex = "/user/(\\w+)\\?name=([a-zA-Z\\s]+)";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
```

you can get hold of `myID123` and `firstName LastName` through `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`

Comment: Minor nitpick: This regex also matches ids starting with a digit.

Comment: True.. the OP's doesn't ;) since it's tagged with homework, I'll leave it as an exercise ;)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the groupings, it really helped clean up my code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any fault in your code but you may capture group like this:

```
    String str = "/user/myID123?name=firstName LastName ";      
    String regex = "/user/([a-zA-Z]+\\w*)\\?name=([a-zA-Z\\s]+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` is greedy by default (it matches the whole string), so you need to modify your regex by adding a `?` (making it reluctant):

```
    List<String> str = Arrays.asList("/user/ad?name=a a", "/user/one111?name=one ONE oNe", "/user/hello?name=world");
    String regex = "/user/([a-zA-Z]+\\w*?)\\?name=([a-zA-Z\\s]+)";

    for (String s : str) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("user: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("name: " + matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
user: ad
name: a a
user: one111
name: one ONE oNe
user: hello
name: world
```

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something else wrong, but this didn't change anything for me :( thanks for your response, though!

Comment: You need to restructure your code and use the Matcher and Pattern classes as in my example.